# Where are labels of a Labeled data used in homomorphic message authenticator stored?

Tags: authentication, authenticated-encryption, homomorphic-signatures

In a fully [homomorphic message authenticator](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/290.pdf), Alice can authenticate
some large data $D$ using her secret key $s$k. She chooses a label $\tau$ for it, and the authentication algorithm authenticates the data $D$ with respect to the label $\tau$.

But, how and where are these labels stored?

Comment: See the `Syntax` part of the article. You send $\sigma$ as the authenticator of the bit and after eval, Verify uses the bit $e$, program $P$ and the tag of the evaluation $\psi$

Comment: @kelalaka  They generate $ \nu = f_{k}(\tau )$ . Then,  output $\sigma= (c_1, . . . , c_n , \nu ) $. How is $ \nu$ stored ?